# Remove automatic back feature of Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

In CentOS 7, Nautilus has this feature that after a time ensures the folder path goes one up i.e.

`/path/abc/xyz/filename.ext`

if Nautilus is left open and no mouse movement then after sometime if goes to

`/path/abc/xyz/`
then
`/path/abc/`

How can one disable this feature like in CentOS 6 where there is no upward 
movement of folder path?

Comment: There is no such feature lol... why would anyone want to implement such a nonsense ? Check your keyboard (hint: the _alt_ and _up_ keys)

Comment: True. This however occurs on most ( if not all ) systems in the network

Comment: Well, something is definitely not right there - I wouldn't know what though (might be a bug in centos nautilus)... I can only guarantee you that this doesn't exist in the upstream `nautilus` - and yes, I know this doesn't help you...